# Converting JSON to CSV using powershell

Tags: json, csv, powershell

I have a very large JSON Lines File with 4.000.000 Rows, and I need to convert several events from every row. The resulted CSV File contains 15.000.000 rows. How can I optimize this script?

I'm using Powershell core 7 and it takes around 50 hours to complete the conversion.

My Powershell script:

```
$stopwatch =  [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
$totalrows = 4000000

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8    
$i = 0
$ig = 0
$output = @()

$Importfile = "C:\file.jsonl"
$Exportfile = "C:\file.csv"

if (test-path $Exportfile) {
    Remove-Item -path $Exportfile
}

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($Importfile, $encoding)) {
    $json = $line | ConvertFrom-Json

    foreach ($item in $json.events.items) {
    $CSVLine = [pscustomobject]@{
    Key = $json.Register.Key
    CompanyID = $json.id
    Eventtype = $item.type
    Eventdate = $item.date
    Eventdescription = $item.description
    }
    $output += $CSVLine
    }

    $i++
    $ig++
    if ($i -ge 30000) {
        $output | Export-Csv -Path $Exportfile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
        $i = 0
        $output = @()

        $minutes = $stopwatch.elapsed.TotalMinutes
        $percentage = $ig / $totalrows * 100
        $totalestimatedtime = $minutes * (100/$percentage)
        $timeremaining = $totalestimatedtime - $minutes

        Write-Host "Events: Total minutes passed: $minutes. Total minutes remaining: $timeremaining. Percentage: $percentage"
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv -Path $Exportfile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Append

$stopwatch.Stop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good article about *performance* to get your started: [*Slow Code: Top 5 ways to make your Powershell scripts run faster*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/); at first sight, here are applicable both parts of *Problem #2 & #3: Appending stuff*:

- Appending to files: `Export-CSV -Append` repeats roughly 133 times (= `4E+6/30E+3` i.e. `4E+6` rows written in chunks of `30E+3` rows each) which **could** considerably worsen performance for big output file;
- Appending to arrays: (**heart of the matter**) *when the `+=` operator is used, it's actually destroying the array and creating a new one* ([source](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/09/28/create-arrays-for-performance-in-powershell.aspx)).

To eliminate appending to arrays, you can use [.NET array list object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1) as follows (merely a hint): replace

- `$output = @()` with `$output = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()`, and
- `$output += $CSVLine` with `[void]$output.Add($CSVLine)`.

Note: do not compute one-purpose variable `$CSVLine` at all; instead, use

```
[void]$output.Add(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Key = $json.Register.Key
        CompanyID = $json.id
        Eventtype = $item.type
        Eventdate = $item.date
        Eventdescription = $item.description
    })
```

Read the [remark about the generic `List<T>` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) and [Performance Considerations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1#performance-considerations) as well:

> In deciding whether to use the `List<T>` or `ArrayList` class, both of
>   which have similar functionality, remember that the `List<T>` class
>   performs better in most cases and is type safe. *If a reference type
>   is used for type `T` of the `List<T>` class, the behavior of the two
>   classes is identical*.